# Can I remove a digital signature from a DLL?

Tags: winapi, dll, code-signing

My installer build "signs" a DLL using a Code Signing certificate during the build process.

I've noticed that if I try to build twice in succession, the second build fails because the DLL is already signed so signcode chokes. Obviously I can fix this by signing a copy of the DLL in the build, but the problem intrigued me:

Is it possible to "unsign" a DLL, and if not, why not...?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
signtool remove /s C:\path\to.exe.or.dll
```

[signtool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx) is available in Windows SDK, and must be at least from Windows 8 SDK kit (version 6.2.9200.20789) to have the `remove` command supported.

Comment: Hm, where have you seen the "remove" command for singtool.exe? Which version is that? Could you please link it? Your existing link does not show it as far as I could see.

Comment: Hm, use "signtool /?" to see the options. @NikolaDavidovic

Comment: Well, it does not have `remove` command. Check it yourself. It is not listed on the link you have provided. So I am asking, what signtool.exe version were you using when you were writing this answer? I checked with product version 6.1.7600.16385.

Comment: I use Visual Studio command prompt: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC>signtool /?
Usage: signtool <command> [options]
 
  Valid commands:
    sign       --  Sign files using an embedded signature.
    timestamp  --  Timestamp previously-signed files.
    verify     --  Verify embedded or catalog signatures.
    catdb      --  Modify a catalog database.
    remove     --  Remove embedded signature(s) or reduce the size of an
                   embedded signed file.
 
For help on a specific command, enter "signtool <command> /?"`

Comment: Thanks @vine'th for your reply. Yes, signtool.exe from Windows 8 SDK kit (version 6.2.9200.20789) has `remove` command as well as higher versions. So in order to have access to it, you should download at least windwos 8 SDK version. Unfortunately I was not able to find MSDN page documenting `remove` command.

Comment: @vine'th It doesn't look too secure if you can just remove the signature. It means that any user could do that, isn't ?

Comment: @JConstantine a certificate is mainly used to indicate: "this file has been approved by a certain authority". When some undefined user removes the certificate, the indication becomes: "this file was modified by an untrusted party". I don't see a problem with that. It is the truth after all.

Answer (score 31):

You can use delcert.exe from the this [XDA Forum post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=2508061).

> here is a small tool that strips (removes) digital sign (Authenticode)
>   from PE executable files like *.exe, *.dll, *.mui, etc.

Comment: This tool uses `ImageRemoveCertificate` API, and works great.

Comment: And it even comes with sources, great.

Answer (score 15):

It's fairly easy to remove the signature from a .dll file using the [ImageRemoveCertificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.

You don't have any language specified in your tags but this article shows how to implement it in C#. [Remove digital signature from a file using C#](http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/remove-digital-signature-from-a-file-using-c/)

Other than that, if you are looking for a simple tool to do the work for you, you can use [FileUnsigner](http://www.fluxbytes.com/software-releases/fileunsigner-v1-0/).

Answer (score 10):

Another possible option is to switch to the [SignTool.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  It comes with the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924) and signing a binary that has already been signed does not generate an error.  I use signtool.exe in my build process and haven't any difficulties with it, even when something is already signed.

Also, check out the question [What's the main difference between signcode.exe and signtool.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770711/whats-the-main-difference-between-signcode-exe-and-signtool-exe)

Answer (score 6):

Sure it's possible, but not trivial.

Although it would be easier to save a copy of the presigned DLL.

This digital signature is little more than an extra section appended to the end of a PE file.  You could write a program that deleted the signature, if you want.

It's not quite as simple as truncating the file; you have to remove references to the signature in the file header.  It could get complicated if the DLL has multiple signatures and you just want to remove one.

The format of a PE file is publicly documented [here](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/PECOFF.mspx)

Comment: Thanks. Not *quite* the answer I hoped for (eg "just run UNSIGNTOOL"), but I'm mich better informed now!

Answer (score 3):

Check if your build tool supports "Re-signing". This should replace all existing signatures.

If not, you can use [Stud_PE](http://www.cgsoftlabs.ro/studpe.html) to remove the signature block.
Open the DLL or EXE in Stud_PE, go to the sections tab, right click the digital signature section and select "Delete section". However, this needs user interaction. Old versions of the tool could destroy the file.