# What's the main difference between signcode.exe and signtool.exe?

Tags: code-signing

I can't really see a big difference other than signtool is newer and requires different file formats for your digital certificate?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They both accomplish the same thing -- code signing. As you pointed out, the principal difference is that `signcode` requires the private key and software publisher certificate to be in two separate files (.pvk, .spc).

The more modern `signtool` requires that they are contained in a single Personal Information Exchange (.pfx) file. (You also need the .pfx file format to use the Association of Shareware Professionals' PAD signing toolkit.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to John Feminella's answer above, signtool allows you to alternatively provide the thumbprint hash of the certificate instead of the .pfx file if the cert is loaded into the local (user or machine) certificate store.

Answer (score 0):

A major difference is that SignCode can run as a Windows GUI and be configurable on demand, while SignTool can be run from the CMD prompt or from a .bat file.