# Where can I find information about signing of files?

Tags: c#

I am interested in learning more about signing files and removing signatures from files, programatically using C#, can anyone recommend a book or website covering this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the excellent [BouncyCastle C# crypto library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/).

It provides plenty of support for signing and verification. It supports [CMS](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3852.txt) the IETFs standard for cryptographically protecting data.

Also:

- Alice and Bob style [introduction to Digital Signatures](http://www.youdzone.com/signature.html)
- An illustrated overview of [how cryptographic hashes work](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/iguide-crypto-hashes.html)
- [How to: Sign XML Documents with Digital Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx)
- [How to: Verify the Digital Signatures of XML Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229950.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Please see [C#: How to Sign and Verify Digital Signatures](http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/04/c-how-to-sign-and-verify-digital.html):

> Beside from the security we squeeze
>   from appliance such as firewall and
>   antivirus, it is a must for our
>   applications to have a second layer of
>   defense. Most often than not you
>   already have several company-wide
>   applications that are interconnected
>   to each other. If you have remote
>   offices, your data will be transmitted
>   over broadband network or internet but
>   how sure are you that each of the
>   application is only accepting data
>   from valid sender? For example, a
>   billing software at remote office that
>   transmits payment confirmation to the
>   financial system located at your head
>   office. Fortunately for .NET
>   developers we can make use of digital
>   certificates. Using digital
>   signatures, we can implement the
>   following security check on our
>   example scenario

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting whitepaper:

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/winlogo/drvsign/best_practices.mspx

Or this http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/12/21/code-signing-it-s-cheaper-and-easier-than-you-thought.aspx link which I've used personally.

Answer (score 0):

[unsingtool.exe](http://koti.mbnet.fi/vaultec/software.php) can remove digital signatures, see [How can I remove a digital signature from a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341168/can-i-remove-a-digital-signature-from-a-dll).

Comment: Tested it but got an error - file does not contain a valid dos header. thanks though, sure it is good for other file types.