# Signing a DLL file after it's already signed?

Tags: dll, code-signing, signtool

Can I safely sign a DLL file with a new certificate (using Microsoft's SignTool) if the DLL is already signed without recompiling it?

Everything **looks** kosher after I do this, but I want to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A digital signature can be appended to a DLL, as long as the [SignTool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx) option which follows is used for signing:

> **/as**
>   Appends this signature. If no primary signature is present, this signature is made the primary signature.

Multiple signing operations do not overwrite/replace the signature.

You might want to refer to [Can I remove a digital signature from a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341168/can-i-remove-a-digital-signature-from-a-dll) for further reference.

---

[Unsigntool](http://koti.mbnet.fi/vaultec/software.php#unsigntool) allows to remove a signature from the PE section - I've never used it nor recommend the usage of this program so, **use it at your own risk**.

The difference - if any - between the files signed twice with or wihout the usage of the `/as` parameter can be seen with some tools like *PE Explorer* / *PE Viewer* which allows to see the PE section of the executable or DLL.

Comment: I have also read the  SignTool docs.  I'ts unclear, what happens if I don't use '/as'? Does the new certificate is being replaced? I want to replace the old one, not append.

Answer (score 2):

You can sign with `SignTool` as many times as you like, and unless you're using the `/as` (append signature) flag, the new signature will replace any old ones. We've used it many times for re-signing a binary whose original signature did not have a timestamp countersignature.

You can check the new signature in the file properties, `Digital Signatures` tab.

Comment: Incidentally, if you neither want to append or replace, but only sign a binary that wasn't signed previously, you can use `signtool verify` or `signtool verify /pa`.