# How can I unsign files from the [Files] section in Inno Setup?

Tags: certificate, inno-setup, signtool

I've been experimenting with certificates and added the `sign` flag for my files in the `[Files]` section. Now all the files are signed with the test certificate. Is there a way to unsign those files?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yes, it does! Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I've faced with this error a couple of times while processing files: `SignTool Error: CryptSIPRemoveSignedDataMsg returned error: 0x00000057` and I've no idea what that error relates to. The signatures were removed anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `signtool` to remove any digital signature from files.

Accordingly to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341168/can-i-remove-a-digital-signature-from-a-dll) you can do:

```
signtool remove /s C:\path\to.exe.or.dll
```