# Is signature just appended to a dll file?

Tags: windows, dll, digital-signature

I have a dll file and get signed by Jenkins, which applies our company's sign tool.
When I compare the signed dll file with the original dll file, I find they are different not only on the last part of the signed file.

E.g. the original dll file's size is 136KB, and the signed dll file's size is 146KB.
I use dd command to remove the additional 10KB data of the signed file and then compare it with the original file, but they are still different. Some difference is in the front of the file, some difference is in the middle of the file.

I just want to know, whether this is right?
In my understanding, the signed dll file should just has some signature part appended to its tail comparing with the original dll file.

Comment: It doesn't get just appended.  The start of the file probably is [the timestamp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#coff-file-header-object-and-image), the middle of the file is probably the [certificate table entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#the-attribute-certificate-table-image-only).  Hack off a certificate the [proper way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341168/can-i-remove-a-digital-signature-from-a-dll).